# 'QueryHelpers' does not exist in the current context - .NET 3.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use `QueryHelpers` to help URL routing, but it isn't working due to

> 'QueryHelpers' does not exist in the current context

I have checked my .NET version, which is 3.1

```
 if (QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query).TryGetValue("initialCount", out var _initialCount))
```

I have also tried using a different method:

```
if (Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.ParseQuery(uri.Query).TryGetValue("initialCount", out var _initialCount))
```

Which again doesn't work. I have also installed the required nuget, [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities/). And still, no luck.

Am I missing something obvious?

Edit:
I have added the full page to add more context

```
@page "/opportunity/{page}"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
@using Linkington.Data
@inject dbFuctions db

Welcome to your new app.


@code {
int currentCount = 0;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    var uri = NavManager.ToAbsoluteUri(NavManager.Uri);
    // if (Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.ParseQuery(uri.Query).TryGetValue("initialCount", out var _initialCount))
    if (QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query).TryGetValue("initialCount", out var _initialCount))
    {
        currentCount = Convert.ToInt32(_initialCount);
    }
}

void IncrementCount()
{
    currentCount++;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your page adding a using to WebUtilities so:

```
@page "/opportunity/{page}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
```

Comment: Wow. I would have thought Visual Studio would make a suggestion to add this. Is this because Blazor is fairly new technology? In webforms for example, if you're missing a using it'll just add it / suggest adding it. Interesting!

Comment: Rider or Resharper do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like below:-

try this:-

```
@page "/opportunity/{page}"
@using Linkington.Data
@inject dbFuctions db
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;  
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;  
@inject NavigationManager navManager 
@code {  
    private int currentCount = 0;  
  
    protected override void OnInitialized()  
    {  
        StringValues _initialCount;  
        var uri = navManager.ToAbsoluteUri(navManager.Uri);  
        if (QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query).TryGetValue("initialCount", out _initialCount))  
        {  
            currentCount = Convert.ToInt32(_initialCount);  
        }  
  
    }  
  
    private void IncrementCount()  
    {  
        currentCount++;  
    }  
}
```

hope to resolve your issue.

Comment: It worked, thanks Pritom. I accepted the other answer as it was only one line of code that was needed, but I appreciate your help!